# search by date goes SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate

I'm working with this entity that has a timeStamp attribute that happens to be a Date type

[image]

Problem comes out, when I try to perform a search by date like:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *end_day = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval: -5*one_day]; // the last 5 days
result = [helper fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"MyEntity" withPredicate:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp > %f", [end_day ] ]];
```

When I print out the value of the predicate, all I get is something like:

```
timestamp > CAST(378132723.717909, "NSDate")
```

But when the statement gets executed, it crashes.
I use the same method in other parts of the code and it work with no problems, and 
obviously if I remove the NSPredicate, again it works.

For the question's sake here's also the code for *fetchObjectsForEnittyName: WithPredicate:*

```
- (NSSet *)fetchObjectsForEntityName:(NSString *)newEntityName
                       withPredicate:(id)stringOrPredicate, ...
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:newEntityName];
    if (stringOrPredicate)
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate;
        if ([stringOrPredicate isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            va_list variadicArguments;
            va_start(variadicArguments, stringOrPredicate);
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringOrPredicate
                                               arguments:variadicArguments];
            va_end(variadicArguments);
        } else {
            NSAssert2([stringOrPredicate isKindOfClass:[NSPredicate class]],
                      @"Second parameter passed to %s is of unexpected class %@",
                      sel_getName(_cmd), @"Whatevah");
            predicate = (NSPredicate *)stringOrPredicate;
        }
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:[error description]];
    }

    return [NSSet setWithArray:results];
}
```

Does anyone have a clue about what the issue might be?

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp > %f", [end_day ] ]]; what does this mean? **[end_day ]**

Comment: it's a typo, it should be %@ instead

Comment: it should be [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp > %@", end_day];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the complex the question seem the easiest the answer is.

i was using

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp > %@", end_day];
```

without the capital S, like described in my entity!
so it should have been

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp > %@", end_day];
```

case solved.

Comment: How small 's' and capital 'S' in nslog's constant string makes the differnce? Did you mean **[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeStamp > %@", end_day];**

Comment: yes, this it the answer. I've edited my reply to make it even clearer

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you're comparing object with scalar and have some extra brackets, try this instead:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp > %@", end_day];
```

second thing to try is format specifier for attribute like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > %@", @"timestamp", end_day];
```